# Multiple Structs Arrays into a single struct type

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm looking to take two struct arrays of array data, retrieved from multiple sources (web REST calls) and cast them into one singular struct array that I can use on a UITableView.

I originally went down the avenue of creating a multidimensional array, but proved difficult when I had to downcast the types as [AnyObject] and couldn't read into the properties.

Example Data:-

```
import UIKit

// First Set Of Data

struct Items : Codable{
    // List of 'items'
    let items : [Item]


}

struct Item: Codable{
    // Items inside the array

    let id : String
    let name : String
    let price : String
    let imageURL : String
    let weight : String

}

// ******** SECOND SET OF DATA

struct SecondSetOfItems : Codable {
    let mainFopCollection : MainFopCollection?

}

struct MainFopCollection : Codable {
    let sections : [Sections]?


}

struct Sections : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let fops : [Fops]?

}


struct Fops : Codable {
    let sku : String?
    let hash : Int?
    let product : Product?

}

struct Product : Codable {
    let sku : String?
    let name : String?
    let price : Price?

}

struct Price : Codable {
    let current : Double?
    let lpp : Bool?
    let unit : Unit?
    let type : String?


}

struct finalSetOfItems{

    let name : String?
    let price: String?


}

var array1 = [Items]()
var array2 = [SecondSetOfItems]()


// Originally tried:-

var multiArray = [[AnyObject]]()

multiArray.append(array1 as [AnyObject])
multiArray.append(array2 as [AnyObject])

// This part errors because I can't access this property
let name = multiArray[1][1].name

// Also tried a ternary operator (this part is within cellforrowat in my UITableViewController but I want the data to be dynamic, and not hard coded.

let name = indexPath.section == 0 ? array1![indexPath.row].name : array2![0].sections![0].fops![indexPath.row].product!.name
```

But then I couldn't access properties of the arrays as the names were too ambiguous, and as I'm using multiple data types it is hard to stipulate what exactly I'm looking for.

The second set of data is considerably more complex (and deeper) than the first set.

**Desired Output:-**

```
// Take complex array1 and array2 and change them into a type of finalSetOfItems
var array1 = [Items]()
var array2 = [SecondSetOfItems]()
var arrayOutput = [finalSetOfItems]()
```

Is there a way i can cast both sets of data into a singular struct type, so the properties can be accessed easier?
The end goal is to cast each array into its own section within a UITableView to denote where the data came from

Apologies if my question is badly worded, I'm still relatively new to Swift. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
let firstItemSet = array1.flatMap{
    $0.items
}.map{
    FinalSetOfItems(name: $0.name, price: $0.price)
}

let secondItemSet = array2.flatMap{
    $0.mainFopCollection?.sections ?? []
}.flatMap{
    $0.fops ?? []
}.compactMap{
    $0.product
}.map{
    FinalSetOfItems(name: $0.name, price: $0.price)
}

let finalSet = firstItemSet + secondItemSet
```

Comment: Hi, I've added more context to the original post. Essentially want to take array1 and array2, and make them fit into a more slimmer struct of [finalSetOfItems]

Comment: @CodeTester9001 I made an edit. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and come back to you (just about to sleep). Looks promising though! Thanks

Comment: If Price became a struct of its own, so I was getting name for example at the current level, but then needed to go another level down for the price, how would I go about doing that? I've edited to the first person to show the Price struct? Thanks in advance

Comment: FinalSetOfItems(name: $0.name, price: $0.price.thePropertyYouWant) ?

Comment: about to sleep, but I tried that before commenting again, but since price is an optional, I think it errors out (tried force unwrapping too). Comes up with an error, something along the lines of ‘the compiler took too long to try this expression’

Comment: Got this when going down this route (Baring in mind, it adds in the optional marker automatically )
'The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions'.

If I did that though, I wouldn't be able to put it into the same array at the same place

Comment: @CodeTester9001 Does your struct Item contains price as Price type instead of String ? Also be careful that FinalSetOfItems should have price as Price type. The compiler just complains that you use wrong type to initialize FinalSetOfItems

Comment: Sorry yes, price.current is a double. So I added that, then did some conversion on the tableview end to get it as a string. Because it wasn't explicitly telling me there was an issue with the type, I wasn't sure what was going on. Thanks for your help once again!